# Calculate DataFrame mode based on a grouped data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following DataFrame:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], "b": [1, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 14, 5], "c": [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]})
>>> df
   a   b  c
0  1   1  1
1  1   5  0
2  1   7  0
3  1   9  1
4  2   2  1
5  2   4  1
6  3   6  1
7  3  14  0
8  3   5  1
```

I want to calculate the mode of column `c` for every unique value in `a` and then select the rows where `c` has this value.

This is my own solution:

```
>>> major_types = df.groupby(['a'])['c'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0])
>>> df = df.merge(major_types, how="left", right_index=True, left_on="a", suffixes=("", "_major"))
>>> df = df[df['c'] == df['c_major']].drop(columns="c_major", axis=1)
```

Which would output the following:

```
>>> df
   a  b  c
1  1  5  0
2  1  7  0
4  2  2  1
5  2  4  1
6  3  6  1
8  3  5  1
```

It is very insufficient for large DataFrames. Any idea on what to do?

Comment: Could you add an output for the data frame snippet you gave us?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) instead `apply` + `merge`

```
df.loc[df['c'].eq(df.groupby('a')['c'].transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0]))]

   a  b  c
1  1  5  0
2  1  7  0
4  2  2  1
5  2  4  1
6  3  6  1
8  3  5  1
```

Or

```
s = df.groupby(['a','c'])['c'].transform('size')
df.loc[s.eq(s.groupby(df['c']).transform('max'))]
```

Comment: The second solution didn't output the same as the first one which is the correct output. I tried both my own solution and the first solution on the full dataset and timed it. My solution took 112.56 seconds while this solution took 147.82 seconds. Any idea on why this is and what to do instead?